# OMDb API Rotten Tomatoes

Tags: api, curl, omdbapi

I believe this may just be a bug in the OMDb API. But I am hoping that someone can point out the errors in my ways.

I am trying to include the Rotten Tomatoes Ratings in a output. But no matter what options I try I don't get anything.

```
curl http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Iron+Man&y=&plot=short&tomatoes=true&r=json
```

Output:

```
   {
             :Title => "Iron Man",
              :Year => "2008",
             :Rated => "PG-13",
          :Released => "02 May 2008",
           :Runtime => "126 min",
             :Genre => "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
          :Director => "Jon Favreau",
            :Writer => "Mark Fergus (screenplay), Hawk Ostby (screenplay), Art Marcum (screenplay), Matt Holloway (screenplay), Stan Lee (characters), Don Heck (characters), Larry Lieber (characters), Jack Kirby (characters)",
            :Actors => "Robert Downey Jr., Terrence Howard, Jeff Bridges, Gwyneth Paltrow",
              :Plot => "After being held captive in an Afghan cave, an industrialist creates a unique weaponized suit of armor to fight evil.",
          :Language => "English, Persian, Urdu, Arabic, Hungarian",
           :Country => "USA",
            :Awards => "Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 17 wins & 52 nominations.",
            :Poster => "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTczNTI2ODUwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTU0NTIzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
         :Metascore => "79",
        :imdbRating => "7.9",
         :imdbVotes => "629,489",
            :imdbID => "tt0371746",
              :Type => "movie",
          :Response => "True"
    }
```

Reference:
http://www.omdbapi.com/

**Update**

In case anyone runs across this (me) again. Here's the expected output with tomatoes:

```
{
                :Title => "Iron Man",
                 :Year => "2008",
                :Rated => "PG-13",
             :Released => "02 May 2008",
              :Runtime => "126 min",
                :Genre => "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
             :Director => "Jon Favreau",
               :Writer => "Mark Fergus (screenplay), Hawk Ostby (screenplay), Art Marcum (screenplay), Matt Holloway (screenplay), Stan Lee (characters), Don Heck (characters), Larry Lieber (characters), Jack Kirby (characters)",
               :Actors => "Robert Downey Jr., Terrence Howard, Jeff Bridges, Gwyneth Paltrow",
                 :Plot => "After being held captive in an Afghan cave, an industrialist creates a unique weaponized suit of armor to fight evil.",
             :Language => "English, Persian, Urdu, Arabic, Hungarian",
              :Country => "USA",
               :Awards => "Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 19 wins & 58 nominations.",
               :Poster => "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTczNTI2ODUwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTU0NTIzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            :Metascore => "79",
           :imdbRating => "7.9",
            :imdbVotes => "635,229",
               :imdbID => "tt0371746",
                 :Type => "movie",
          :tomatoMeter => "94",
          :tomatoImage => "certified",
         :tomatoRating => "7.7",
        :tomatoReviews => "266",
          :tomatoFresh => "249",
         :tomatoRotten => "17",
      :tomatoConsensus => "Director Jon Favreau and star Robert Downey Jr. make this smart, high impact superhero movie one that even non-comics fans can enjoy.",
      :tomatoUserMeter => "91",
     :tomatoUserRating => "4.2",
    :tomatoUserReviews => "1072111",
                  :DVD => "30 Sep 2008",
            :BoxOffice => "$318.3M",
           :Production => "Paramount Pictures",
              :Website => "http://www.ironmanmovie.com/",
             :Response => "True"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have to wrap your url inside the quote. Otherwise the `&` causing you the problem by breaking the command on that position.

```
curl "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Iron+Man&y=&plot=short&tomatoes=true&r=json"
```

Comment: Sigh, I can't believe I missed this. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: same problem here :)